# Como recuperar os nameservers fornecidos pela aws?

Tags: amazon-aws

Deletei sem querer os 4 nameserver fornecidos pela aws.

Como recuperar ?

Answer (score 1):

Para obter os servidores de nome de uma zona hospedada usando o console do Route 53

Faça login no Console de gerenciamento da AWS e abra o console do Route 53 em https://console.aws.amazon.com/route53/.

No painel de navegação, clique em Zonas hospedadas.

Na página Zonas hospedadas, marque o botão circular (não o nome) para a zona hospedada.

No painel direito, anote os quatro servidores listados para Servidores de nomes.

[Fonte](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/GetInfoAboutHostedZone.html)

[image: exemplo]